# Click on row with JS

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript which I use to open a new page when I click on table row:

```
//for clicking on a row in tabs and opening new page
function addOnclickToTabsDatatableRows() {
    //gets all the generated rows in the html table
    var trs = document.getElementById('formname:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('tr');
    //on every row, add onclick function (this is what you're looking for)
    for (var i = 0; trs.length > i; i++) {
        var cells = trs[i].cells;                    
        for(var j=1; j < cells.length; j++){
            cells[j].onclick = new Function("rowOnclick(this.parentElement)");
        }                    
    }
}
```

I noticed a problem which I cannot solve. I apply this JS script on several pages. Into every page I have a different forms with different Ids. Now if I want to use this JS I have to have every form with id `formname`. How I can apply this JS for every form no matter what Id is there? Is there any standard approach that I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `document.getElementById('formname:dataTable')`, just use `document.getElementsByTagName("form")`

Comment: This. Also for ease of use I would recommend using jquery which makes element targeting/selection delightfully easy. Check http://jquery.com/ for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over all the forms in the page, like so:

```
for(var i=0;i<document.forms.length;i++) {
    var trs = document.forms[i].getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('tr');
    // rest of your code..
}
```